# How to create a class method to find by two different Active Record relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to solve an issue.
I have this class

```
class UserWebexClassroom < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PGEnum

  belongs_to :attendee, class_name: :User, foreign_key: :user_id, inverse_of: :attendee_classrooms
  belongs_to :classroom, class_name: :WebexClassroom, primary_key: :external_id, foreign_key: :webex_classroom_external_id, inverse_of: :attendee_classrooms
  has_one :webex, through: :classroom

  validates_inclusion_of :status, in: statuses.values

end

UserWebexClassroom
 => UserWebexClassroom(id: integer, user_id: integer, webex_classroom_external_id: integer, status: enum)
```

This is a system to track the presence of some people in some Webex Sessions.

I'm trying to find the most efficient way to find the istances of this class passing the webex and the user.

Is there an active record method to find by two different relations?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure, but I guess you could do:

```
UserWebexClassroom.joins(:webex).where(webex: {id: webex}, user: user)
```

This is assuming the name of your `webex` table is `webex`, however if it's `webexes`, you should rather have:

```
UserWebexClassroom.joins(:webex).where(webexes: {id: webex}, user: user)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to have associations in every model set up correctly.

```
class WebexClassroom < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attendee_classrooms, class_name: :UserWebexClassroom

  # this line is very important, or the query won't be done with correct join conditions
  has_one :webex, primary_key: :external_id, foreign_key: :webex_classroom_external_id
end

class Webex < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :webex_classroom, primary_key: :external_id, foreign_key: :webex_classroom_external_id
end
```

Then you could query to get all `user_id` for one webex with id: `1`

```
[58] pry(main)> UserWebexClassroom.includes("webex").where("webexes.id = ?", 1).references("webexes")
  SQL (0.2ms)  SELECT "user_webex_classrooms"."id" AS t0_r0, "user_webex_classrooms"."user_id" AS t0_r1, "user_webex_classrooms"."webex_classroom_external_id" AS t0_r2, "webexes"."id" AS t1_r0, "webexes"."webex_classroom_external_id" AS t1_r1 FROM "user_webex_classrooms" LEFT OUTER JOIN "webex_classrooms" ON "webex_classrooms"."external_id" = "user_webex_classrooms"."webex_classroom_external_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "webexes" ON "webexes"."webex_classroom_external_id" = "webex_classrooms"."external_id" WHERE (webexes.id = 1)
=> [#<UserWebexClassroom:0x007fdea4643720 id: 1, user_id: 2, webex_classroom_external_id: 1>, #<UserWebexClassroom:0x007fdea4641628 id: 2, user_id: 4, webex_classroom_external_id: 1>]
```

The answer by @oreoluwa won't work because `joins` assume you are using the simple association, without `through` option, without customized foregien keys. If you would like to do with `joins`, you have to specify the join conditions explicitly.

UPDATE:

Here are my schema and other two models:

```
# db/schema.rb

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160619045919) do

  create_table "user_webex_classrooms", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "webex_classroom_external_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  end

  create_table "webex_classrooms", primary_key: "external_id", force: :cascade do |t|
  end

  create_table "webexes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "webex_classroom_external_id"
  end

end

# app/models/user.rb

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attendee_classrooms, class_name: :UserWebexClassroom
end

# app/models/user_webex_classroom.rb

class UserWebexClassroom < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attendee, class_name: :User, foreign_key: :user_id, inverse_of: :attendee_classrooms
  belongs_to :classroom, class_name: :WebexClassroom, primary_key: :external_id, foreign_key: :webex_classroom_external_id, inverse_of: :attendee_classrooms
  has_one :webex, through: :classroom
end
```

Comment: Can we see your schema please